# How to install Miktex on Centos 7?

Tags: anaconda, latex, pdflatex, miktex, texmaker

Can anyone suggest me how I can install miktex on Centos 7?
While I find the instructions for installing Miktex on Centos 8 at https://miktex.org/download, I was not able to install the same even if I try the same commands on Centos 7 after installing 'dnf'. I could not succeed.
I have tried to install miktex through anaconda installer (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/miktex) but could not succeed and the error is displayed as "PackagesNotFoundError".

Can anyone suggest me how I can install miktex on Centos 7?

Comment: Why would you want to use miktex on centos? Do yourself a favour and use texlive!

Comment: I have tried installing texlive. Installed successfully without any issues. I get the following errors/issues when I compile the tex document in Texmaker:

`Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

If I run the tex document in Texstudio, I get the following error: 

`Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode`

I don't have any clue on why the above error is coming?

Comment: Is pdflatex in your path? Otherwise you could try to give the complete path in your texstudio/texmaker prefereces

Comment: Following is the complete path for pdflatex in the configuration settings: `"/home/madhavan/anaconda2/bin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. I get the following error: `Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX:
"/home/madhavan/anaconda2/bin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode`. Please suggest me how I can rectify this issue.

Comment: That sounds like a highly unusual location for pdflatex. To make sure it is correctly installed, can you test from a terminal if `/home/madhavan/anaconda2/bin/pdflatex name_of_your_tex_file` works?

Comment: I issue seems to be that Anaconda itself or some package in anaconda installs an incomplete LaTeX.  In fact, I have installed the tex-live package (alternative to Miktex) through root at `/usr/bin/' directory. When I changed the path specifications at the Configuration window of TexStudio, it was working fine. Somehow, the paths are configured by default to anaconda path, which is incomplete tex installation. Before changing the path, I have run the following commands to install the missing formats, if any:
**fmtutil --help**

**fmtutil --all**

Comment: rule of thumb: anaconda is always a problem :)

Comment: Why MikTeX vs TeXLive? For me, simple -- package management under MikTeX is light-years beyond TexLive. IMO.